# Jquery Multi Delete Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, droppable

```
function clear(node) {
  if (Obj != null) {
    $.each(Obj, function(key, val) {
      if ($('#selectable li#' + key).length == 1) {
        $('#selectable li#' + key).replaceWith('<span id="' + key + '"></span>');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

With this Function i can "delete" one Objects in the List, when it's the only one. Then i just replace the list with a empty span.

```
if ($('#selectable li#' + key).length > 1) {
  $.each($('#selectable li#' + key + 'a'), function(k, v) {
    var href = $(v).attr('href');
    if (endsWith(href, val)) {
      $(v).parent().remove();
    }
  });
}
```

This is how i delete one Object from the List, now i am trying to select 2 Objects and delete them but i cant success in that. I tryied something like this:

```
if ($('#selectable li#' + key).length >= 2) {
  $.each($('#selectable li#' + key + 'a'), function(k, v) {
    var href = $(v).attr('href');
    if (endsWith(href, val)) {
      $(v).parent().remove(('#selectable li#' + key).length);
    }
  });
}
```

Thanks for Support

Comment: that´s javascript and not java...

Comment: It doesn't have anything related to drag & drop either

Comment: I've answered below but I'm a bit concerned that you might have duplicate ids in your markup. The `#` selector picks up ids, which should always be unique, so the resulting set of elements should always be empty or length 1. Browsers will allow you treat ids like classes though, so it's possible to get away with it.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it much more simply, using something like this:

```
$('#selectable li#'+key).has("a[href$="+val+"]").remove();
```

I'll try and break that down a bit:

```
$('#selectable li#'+key)
```

That's your original selector.

```
.has(...)
```

This filters the results to just the ones that have contents that matches a selector.

```
"a[href$="+val+"]"
```

This is the selector for the `has(...)` above. It means `<a>` elements with `href` attributes that end with `val`.

```
.remove()
```

This removes the resulting set of elements from the DOM.